# What does 一 + verb/noun + 一 + verb/noun mean?

Tags: grammar

I’m reading 活着 and I’m seeing it all the time. It’s driving me nuts!

“他才挠着头一步一步往回走。”

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example 一步一步 basically means "step by step"; it emphasizes how it's gradual and slow.  More generally it means "little by little", and the repeated character indicates what is occurring gradually.

> Aside from just meaning "one by one," when 一 (yī) is used with a measure word that is a unit of time like "day" or "year," the meaning changes to "little by little" ("day by day," "year by year") or "gradually."
>   <sub>[Expressing "one by one" with "yi": Used as "Little by Little"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22one_by_one%22_with_%22yi%22#Used_as_.22Little_by_Little.22), Chinese Grammar Wiki</sub>

I found the relevant passage from 活着 and it's:

> 凤霞走后，有庆不干了。起先凤霞被人领走时，有庆瞪着眼睛还不知道出了什么事，直到凤霞走远了，**他才挠着头一步一步往回走**。我看到他朝我这里张望几下，就是不过来问我。他还在家珍肚子里时我就打过他，他看到我怕。

Here's my rough, somewhat literal translation:

> After Feng Xia left, Youqing stopped.  At first, when Feng Xia was taken away, Youqing's open eyes didn't know what happened, and when Feng Xia was far away, **only then he scratched his head and step-by-step walked back**.  I saw him face me here peering for a bit, but did not come over and ask me.  When he was still in Jiazhen's tummy I beat him, and he saw my fear.

And a professional translation:

> After Fengxia left, Youqing stopped listening to us.  When Fengxia was taken away, Youqing just watched, not knowing what was going on.  **Only** after Fengxia had gotten far away **did Youqing scratch his head and slowly make his way home**.  I saw him looking over at me a few times, but he didn't come over to ask what was going on.  When he was still in Jiazhen's stomach I had hit him, so he was scared of me.
>   <sub>To Live: A Novel, Yu Hua, translated by Michael Berry</sub>