# How should I interpret the 一……一 construct used in 一爱一岗 and 睫一毛一?

Tags: meaning

> ……父母是子女的第一位启蒙教师，要培养子女的责任感、事业心，家长首先就要敬业**一爱一岗**，有强烈的责任感、事业心。……
> <sub>[大禹治水](https://www.xyyuedu.com/etdw/zhongguolishidiangu/290188.html)</sub>

> ……大王，您想错了。我虽然见识不多，但我知道，人的智慧往往就同人的眼睛一样，能见百步以外的东西，却看不见自己的**睫一毛一**。……
> <sub>[目不见睫](https://www.xyyuedu.com/etdw/zhongguolishidiangu/290281.html)</sub>

I'm not sure how to interpret the 一……一 phrases above.  I've encountered [一举一动](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%BE%E4%B8%80%E5%8A%A8) = "every movement / each and every move" and 一步一步 (like in [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/39531/8099)) which means something like "step by step", so maybe it's related.  Perhaps 睫一毛一 means something like "each and every eyebrow", but I'm not sure about 一爱一岗.

**Question**: How should I interpret the 一……一 construct used in 一爱一岗 and 睫一毛一?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s a typo and should be deleted. Never heard of this in my life.  Google search also confirms it.

Comment: I see.  Perhaps randomly adding in 一……一 is their method for thwarting bots and preventing plagiarism.

Comment: The point is taken. However, there is a first time for everything. If you could go back in time and said, say, 电脑, to a typical Chinese speaker in the 1960s, the latter would have said, quite rightly, it do not exist in Chinese vocabulary, notwithstanding that it might be in closed circulation among academics. My point is that a living language, (of which Chinese is one), evolves to cater for the existential needs of its users, present and future, otherwise the language dies. Perhaps the two controversial phrases, accidental typos or otherwise, may come in useful one day. Who knows?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of understanding what the author of those two passages is trying to say, I think the messages conveyed are clear enough, though the way he chose to say them may be, shall I say, "individualistic", or may be even "poetic" It's about style, I suppose.

I'll take each passage in turn.

Let's take the easy part of the first one first:- "...要培养子女的责任感, ....家长首先就要敬业...."

The simple message is that "in order to inculcate a sense of responsibility in children,...parents should first dedicate...."

Now comes the hard part:- "一爱一岗" By itself it is unintelligible. But for the sake of today's discussion, let's see how it fits in with the rest of the passage.

Given the simple meaning of the first part of the passage, could we then say that 一爱一岗 means, in the context of the whole passage, "...in order to inculcate a sense of responsibility in children,...parents should first of all dedicate a mountain of love....", or words to that effect. 一爱一岗 = "a hill of a love"?

Now for the next passage which I think is much easier than the first.

The relevant part of the passage:- "...能见百步以外的东西，却看不见自己的睫一毛一"

It simply means:- "...able to see things a 100 paces away, but unable to see one's own eyelashes..." The "一毛一" simply means, (for poetic effect), "each of one hair"

So, to paraphrase the passage:- "...able to see things a 100 paces away, but unable to see each of one hair of one's eyelashes..."

Please do this simple experiment:- Try to see something far away, (no problem right?); now try and see your own eyelashes?

Hence the King's advisor said in the passage "....人的智慧往往就同人的眼睛一样,能见百步以外的东西，却看不见自己的睫一毛一", meaning "the intelligence of people is often like human eyes"; able to see things a 100 paces away, but unable to see even one hair of one's own eyelashes...", meaning, people tend to talk of great things easily, but unable to grasp simple ideas just as easily.

This reminds me of 越近越朦朧 越遠越情濃, meaning to the effect that people tend to be concerned with things which have not much personal importance or concerns, but neglect things or matters which are near and dear to them. Like some people who want to save the World but couldn't clean up their own backyard.

Answer (score 1):

They are typos.
爱岗敬业 and 睫毛 are correct,  敬业一爱一岗 and 一睫一毛 do not exist in Chinese vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

These "一" are in fact meaningless characters inserted in certain words to circumvent censorship. Websites often filter for adult content via blacklists of explicit or suggestive words. Sometimes these filters are implemented by simply searching for instances of a word or character without regard for context. Combined with blacklists compiled with a very low threshold of suggestiveness, this can lead to innocuous texts being blocked. If you sample a few more pages from this website, you will notice that the words in which these extra characters appear are of this kind.